# Reasons to mask signals?

Tags: c, signals, masking

So this isn't code related at all, just conceptual.  What are some reasons for a proces to mask signals at any point in their execution?  I get the concept of signals and masking, just can't think of any specific examples of reasons to mask signals.

Answer (score 1):

An example: a parent process forks a child, doesn't care if/when the child dies and does not want to be interrupted while performing a blocking operation... so it masks `SIGCHILD`.

But your question really is far too broad for this forum.

Comment: thanks, I realize it's a very broad question but I haven't found an answer elsewhere